# One line check map item exists and process in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I have seen it is common to check an item is not `null`/`undefined` before executing code. For example to check a variable is a number and not `undefined` before printing it:

```js
const printNum = (n: number) => console.log(n);
const x: undefined | number = undefined;
x && printNum(x);
```

I want to do something similar with a `Map` object, whereby I check if the item exists in `Map`, and if so performs some code, all on 1 line.

At the moment the only way I can think of is checking it exists using `Map.has()` then `Map.get()` but casting to the appropriate type, as in the example below `Map.get()` still returns type `undefined | A`. Or, retrieve the item into a variable and then check for `null`/`undefined` (but this is over 2 lines). Is there a more elegant or simple solution I am missing?

```js
class A{
    constructor(public n: number) {}
}
const printA = (aObj: A) => console.log(aObj.n);
let m = new Map<string, A>([
    ["firstItem", new A(10)],
    ["secondItem", new A(20)]
]);
// better way to do this?
m.has("firstItem") && printA(m.get("firstItem") as A);

// or could do it this way
const a = m.get("firstItem");
a && printA(a);
```

Comment: "Better" is opinion-based, which is off-topic for SO. ("Better" in my book, for instance, would be to use `if` rather than side-effecty `&&` operations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` knew how to print itself by having a `print` method that calls `printA`, you could use [*optional chaining*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
m.get("firstItem")?.print();
//                ^^−−−− optional chaining
```

But if it's a separate function or a method on some other object, that won't work.

Setting aside subjective definitions of "better," doing a `has` check followed by a `get` means looking for the key in the `Map` twice rather than once. In 99.99% of maps (at least ), it won't matter, but I would do this:

```typescript
const item = m.get("firstItem");
if (item) {
    printA(item);
}
```

You don't need the assertion because TypeScript can see from the check that `item` won't be `undefined`.

Some people would leave off those curly braces to make it a two-liner:

```typescript
const item = m.get("firstItem");
if (item) printA(item);
```

You could do it with `&&` as well:

```typescript
const item = m.get("firstItem");
item && printA(item);
```

But I don't think there's a reasonable way to do it in a single statement. There are ways I think most people would consider *un*reasonble:

```typescript
const item = m.get("firstItem"), _ = item && printA(item);
```

That creates a `_` constant that is never actually used. But of course, if you do it again, you have to use `_2` or something.

Comment: Ah ok, that actually makes sense now why TS wouldn't return type `A` from `get()` as there is no guarantee the item still exists after the `has()` call. I would like to use assignment like `if (let item=m.get("firstItem")) printA(item)`  but TS doesn't allow that